# Are you expected to build the .jar files yourself?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am very new to Android (just two days old) and am trying to implement the downloader for apk expansion files for a game by extending DownloaderService class. I have installed the Licensing Library, APK Expansion Library package from the SDK Manager and noticed that it left *.java files on under my SDK path. I was expecting jar files for these. Reading the online documentation gives me the impression that I am supposed to build that myself. Is my understanding correct ? Is this a normal practice in Android ?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, is it possible to do this with NDK ? I couldn't find any references to it in NDK documentation ?